# Is it possible to have Indigo or Hydro along with Kinetic on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ros-hydro, ros-indigo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to stimulate the 1st edition Darwin OP, but it requires ROS Hydro or Indigo. The installation states the packages cant be found. I know they are meant for older versions of Ubuntu, but would it be possible to install them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315421/is-it-possible-to-have-indigo-or-hydro-along-with-kinetic-on-ubuntu-16.04?/) by [FarLeviTes](https://answers.ros.org/users/39984/farlevites/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why don't you try docker? I run all the ROS stuff under docker so it doesn't kill my OpenCV library

---

Originally posted by [kolya_rage](https://answers.ros.org/users/35353/kolya_rage/) with karma: 76 on 2019-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0